# As in the picture when I connect the gnd of hlw8012 to the gnd of esp8266 I get electric shock .what should I do now

Tags: ground, esp8266, nodemcu, shock, iot

[image]

I'm working on a project based on Iot so I was using hlw8012 for power monitoring and after connecting the IC module to the esp8266 whenever I touch the Esp module I get electric shock . What should I do now ??

Comment: What you should do now is STOP.  You're working with a non-isolated circuit connected directly to mains, and if you don't understand exactly what you're doing you're in danger.  Find someone experienced with these types of circuits to work with.

Comment: you have a circuit that is directly connected to power lines, why are you surprised that you get a shock? ... go buy a lottery ticket because you are very lucky today

Comment: That is dangerous. Stop touching it, unplug it and make sure no one accidentally plugs it in again. Only when immediate danger has been removed, you can go back to designing a safe circuit. Often live circuits (such as USB or laptop chargers) are put into plastic boxes so no one can touch live parts.

Comment: The OP's circuit seems to be taken from the HLW8012 manufacturer documentation https://itead.cc/sonoff/introducting-the-hlw8012-ic-in-the-sonoff-pow/ as a typical application.

Answer (score 4):

FIRST and foremost, please stop playing with lethal AC mains, until you totally understand the dangers, or get someone with appropriate knowledge and experience to guide you.

You need to isolate the current measuring shunt on the mains from the measurement circuitry. One method is a high side current monitor like the [HV7801](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/HV7801%20A062813.pdf), which is not actually isolated, but has a quiescent current of only 50 uA, which is below the normal threshold of sensation for AC currents.

You should read, and understand, the need for and principles of isolated current sensing, which are pretty well covered here:

https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/isolated-current-sensors-solve-circuit-safety-problems

Hall effect current sensors are also very useful and safe:

https://www.ti.com/product/TMCS1101

https://www.makerguides.com/acs712-current-sensor-and-arduino-a-complete-guide/